How to name spherical molecules?
A couple months ago, I put together a distorted spherical molecule with moly mods while messing about. Seeing as Carbon 60 is named fullerene, how do you go about naming other spherical compounds? I thought that it would start depending on the types of arenes present but I would imagine that this is the incorrect way to do it.

What "spherical molecules"? Fullerenes are a whole class of carbon molecules, not necessarily all that spherical.

We name fullerenes "fullerenes".

@Mithoron Like a cylindrical shape or and orb like how the different fullerenes can be formed but had other elements like say nitrogen for example at similar positions around. For example if you had a cylindrical shape of a pyridine.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Azafullerene

You might be referring to heterofullerene. They are a class of fullerenes where at least one carbon atom is replaced by another element. The most popularly studied is azafullerene.
Regarding nomenclature of heterofullerene, you can refer to this documentation.
